# Partial Differential Equations: Find an explicit solution of IVP for diffusion equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, convolution, heat-equation

Find an explicit solution of IVP for the diffusion equation:

$u_{t}=u_{xx}, x \in\ {R}, t>0$

$u(0,x)=x, x\in R$

So, I used the normalization integral, differentiated it in t and then rearranging the terms of that newly obtained equation I got that it equals to 2t. And then substituted the integrals which yield the closed explicit expression for u(x,t)=......=x

Could someone confirm that it's a correct solution or if it's not, could you please post how you solved this problem so I can figure out where I made a mistake!

Thank you so much! Would highly appreciate your help!

Comment: its a solution, yes

Comment: By normalisation integral, do you mean the [heat kernel?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_kernel)